# Multiple parameters in ParameterizedThreadStart, c++/cli

Tags: c++, multithreading, command-line-interface

Using ParameterizedThreadStart (System::Threading) allow to pass an argument of calling function. But it's not comfortable to declare an Object^ type of this parameter. Is there any way to specify an exact type of such parameter? And how to pass multiple parameters in that function?

Comment: Just declare a little helper class with as many properties as you need and pass an instance of it as the argument.  Cast it back in the thread method from Object^ to your helper class with safe_cast<>.

Comment: @Hans Passant Thanks! But i've got an error using this code: void myfunc(Object^ obj)
 {
 hh=safe_cast<helper^>(obj); Console::WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}",hh->a,hh->b,hh->c);}   "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  (int a,b,c received from helper constructor)